# Android doInBackground task not running... but pre execute runs

Tags: php, android, mysql

i am running an android app connected with mysql, i am using php files to login and register the user, i have already added a data to the db, and i am trying to login using these details.

I have a different class named Background worker to do the asynctask. The doInBackground task does not run but the pre execute task runs in the app.

These are the login and register files in php which is stored in the local host...

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name = "user_name";
$user_pass = "password";
$mysql_query = "select * from users where Email like '$user_name' and Password like '$user_pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "login success";
}
else {
    echo "login not success";
}
?>
```

Register.php

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$name = "name";
$user_name = "user_name";
$user_pass = "password";
$cpass = "cpass";
$mysql_query = "insert into users (Name,Email,Password,ConfirmPass) values ('$name','$user_name','$user_pass','$cpass')";
if($conn->query($mysql_query) === TRUE){
    echo "You have successfully registered!";
}
else {
    echo "Register failed";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This is my Login.java page in android:

```
package com.example.user.smartkitchen;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button login,loginResetPass,RegisterLinkButton;
    EditText UserNameTxt, PasswordTxt;
    //private FirebaseAuth auth;
    public static final String Email = "Email";
    public ImageButton exit;
    //private ProgressBar progressBar;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
        */
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        UserNameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserNameTxt);
        PasswordTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordTxt);
        //progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        RegisterLinkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RegisterLinkButton);
        RegisterLinkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Register.class));
            }
        });


    }

    public void onLogin(View view) {
        String username = UserNameTxt.getText().toString();
        String password = PasswordTxt.getText().toString();
        String type = "login";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type,username,password);
    }

       /* loginResetPass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginResetPass);



        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();




        loginResetPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, forgotPassword.class));
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = UserNameTxt.getText().toString();
                final String password = PasswordTxt.getText().toString();
                String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (email.matches(emailPattern))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        PasswordTxt.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("Email", email);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

    }

    public void onExitTapped(View view) {

        exit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        finish();
    }
*/

}
```

This is my Background Worker Class:

```
package com.example.user.smartkitchen;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by User on 8/6/2017.
 */

public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_URL = "http://192.168.1.7/login.php";
        String register_URL = "http://192.168.1.7/register.php";
        if(type.equals("login")){
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_URL);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    result +=line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(type.equals("register")){
            try {
                String name = params[1];
                String user_name = params[2];
                String password = params[3];
                String cpass = params[4];
                URL url = new URL(register_URL);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data1 = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")+"&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8")+"&" +
                URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("cpass", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(cpass, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data1);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    result +=line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
```

I get the alert dialog with title set, but the success message does not appear, is the php page not running? Can someone pls help?

Comment: Can you put some logs or debug pointers to check what happens when code goes to background method. Does it not go even to 1st line or does it stop somewhere else.

Comment: if the alert bar is showing it means onPostExecute() is working and also doInBackground(). because you have call         alertDialog.show();
in onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

you are using POST in http,

```
so in php you should use :

if(isset($_POST['user_name']))
{
$user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
}

Hope it works
```